# Finding duration with time stamp in rows & sum of column elements upto certain order_id in rows (python)

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, data-science, addition

Here's my data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nyvx2GXUFLxrJdRTIKNAqIVvGP7FyiQ9NrjKiHoX3kE/edit?usp=sharing

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDfb1.png)

It's a small part of dataset with 100s of order_id.

1. I want to find duration in @timestamp column with respect to order_id. Example. for order_id 3300400, duration will be from index 6 to index 0. Similarly for all other order ids.
2. I want to have the sum of items.quantity and items.price with respect to order ids. Ex. for order_id 3300400, sum of items.quantity = 2 and sum of items.price = 499+549 = 1048. Similarly for other order_ids.

I am new to python but I think it will need the use of loops. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Shantanu Jain

Comment: Can you copy and paste your data rather than using an image please ?

Comment: Hi GhandhiFloss, I have added the google sheet link to dataset. Please help me..

Comment: Hi @GhandiFloss, I have added the dataset, please can you help me.

Comment: i haven't got much time at the moment. Look up pandas.groupby(). You should be able to group by order_id and get your sums easily

Comment: Okay, thanks @GhandiFloss. I will search it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @GhandiFloss, I was able to figure out the addition for values. If you could just shed some light on how to find the duration also, using groupby function. I would be highly obliged.

Answer (score 0):

you have figured out how to use the groupby() method which is good. In order to work out the diff in timestamps its a little more work.

```
# Function to get first and last stamps within group
def get_index(df):
    return df.iloc[[0, -1]]

# apply function and then use diff method on ['@timestamp']
df['time_diff'] = df.groupby('order_id').apply(get_index)['@timestamp'].diff()
```

I haven't tested any of this code, and it will only work if your time stamps are pd.timestamps. It should at least give you an idea on where to start

Comment: Thanks @GhandiFloss! I will surely try it.